# PHP $_GET from a form undefined array error

Tags: php, forms, get

I'm currently learning PHP from the very basic and started following a 2 year old youtube video. I'm trying to make a simple php calculator based from his code, but I've run into an error despite copying 100% of the example code, I'm guessing this is due to the version difference. What can be done to fix this issue, error code says undefined array, does this mean that I just need to pre-define the variables? How would I do this.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <form action="site.php" method="get">
      <input type="number" name="num1">
      <br>
      <input type="number" name="num2">
      <br>
      <input type="submit">
    </form>

  Answer: <?php echo $_GET["num1"] + $_GET["num2"] ?>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @RGriffiths yes, that's the exact code he was using as an example, and it was working in his video.

use dot like this?

Answer: <?php echo $_GET["num1"] . $_GET["num2"] ?>

it gives the same error

Comment: Forget the dot thing. name = "num1", name = "num2" you have missed the equals

Comment: @RGriffiths Hi thank you very much for pointing that out, I did miss the = and that was very dumb of me. The code is working now, but the error still persist.

ERROR: Warning: Undefined array key "num1" in C:\Users\Kenji\www\site.php on line 17

Comment: You're not checking to see if the form has been submitted. If it hasn't the `$_GET` array will be empty and you'll get the error you're seeing. The `$_GET` variables will only exist when the form is actually submitted.

Answer (score 1):

Explanation:

In the past (old php versions) it was not necessary to define/declare variables.
This has changed and now you will get warnings/notices.

If you call the page for the first time the variables num1 and num2 are not defined - that will result in that warning. Only when you enter them and send the form then they will have a value.

So insert a condition if that variables are empty and only if they are NOT empty make the calculation and print it.

! means [NOT](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php#language.operators.logical)

isset() checks if the variable exists.
https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.isset
(empty was  a wrong  approach because 0 is a valid entry as one commenter pointed thankfully out)

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <form action="site.php" method="get">
      <input type="number" name="num1">
      <br>
      <input type="number" name="num2">
      <br>
      <input type="submit">
    </form>

  Answer: <?php 

if ((!isset($_GET["num1"]) && (!isset($_GET["num1"])){ 
    echo $_GET["num1"] + $_GET["num2"]; 
}

?>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Warning: since you're dealing with inputs of type `number`, you might want to use `isset()` rather than `!empty()` (or a combination of both). `empty($_GET["num1"])` will return `true` if the entered value is zero.

Comment: @rickdenhaan   you are right -   I never had the situation before that 0 may be a valid entry ;-)   but yes 0+5 is a valid entry

Comment: @rickdenhaan i updated the answer to reflect your comment. thx.